# MYSQL - how to select with group by and having

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I have this schema:

```
table = users
user_id - integer
user_name - string

table = transaction
transaction_id - string
user_id - integer
```

this sample data:

```
user_id -  user_name
2       -  Jhon
3.      -  barry

transaction_id - user_id
19123          -  2
20123          -  2
20124          -  2
21123          -  2
```

I need to get how many transactions the user jhon did in 19 and 20 only
the first 2 digits from the transaction_id is the year, but I can't seem to group them, what I have is:

```
select u.user_name
from transaction t join users u on u.user_id = t.user_id
group by (substr(t.transaction_id, 1, 2))
where <I have no idea in how to fill this>
```

what I want as a result is:

```
jhon 1 2
```

1 transction in 19
2 transactions in 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better  to save dates in mysql way 2022-12-31, so you cqan use date function withput converting.

You need to GROUP By Nam,ame and the first 2 digits

And the WHERE clause belongs always before the group by

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (
>   `user_id` INTEGER,
>   `user_name` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO users
>   (`user_id`, `user_name`)
> VALUES
>   ('2', 'Jhon'),
>   ('3.', 'barry');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE transaction (
>   `transaction_id` INTEGER,
>   `user_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO transaction
>   (`transaction_id`, `user_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('19123', '2'),
>   ('20123', '2'),
>   ('20124', '2'),
>   ('21123', '2');
> ```

> ```
> select u.user_name, Count(*)
> from transaction t join users u on u.user_id = t.user_id
> where u.user_name = 'Jhon' AND (substr(t.transaction_id, 1, 2)) IN  (19,20)
> group by u.user_name,(substr(t.transaction_id, 1, 2))
> ```

> ```
> user_name | Count(*)
> :-------- | -------:
> Jhon      |        1
> Jhon      |        2
> ```

> ```
> select u.user_name
> , SUM((substr(t.transaction_id, 1, 2)) = 19) As `Count_19`
> , SUM((substr(t.transaction_id, 1, 2)) = 20) As `Count_20`
> from transaction t join users u on u.user_id = t.user_id
> where u.user_name = 'Jhon' AND (substr(t.transaction_id, 1, 2)) IN  (19,20)
> group by u.user_name
> ```

> ```
> user_name | Count_19 | Count_20
> :-------- | -------: | -------:
> Jhon      |        1 |        2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=66efa5e41588c2d54097b45f8fd9cf91)*

Comment: I cant recreate the tables or alter data

Comment: no problem, the queries work fine, the suggestions are also for future reference